# ¿Cómo restringir campo de SQL para que no permita ingresar datos diferentes a "FIJO" o "INDEFINIDO"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, validación, sql-server-2019

Hola buenos días a todos.
Estoy creando una tabla de vacaciones en SQL Server 2019

Quiero crear una columna que se llama "TIPO CONTRATO" en donde solo se permita ingresar dos valores de tipo texto, los valores serian "FIJO" o "INDEFINIDO" porque no puedo hacerle tramite de vacaciones a los empleados que no cuenten con ese tipo de contratación y evitar que mi tabla a futuro tenga incoherencia en la información.
¿Hay alguna forma de hacer eso?

Agradezco me puedan ayudar...

Comment: y porque la tabla tiene que controlar una regla de negocio? y de paso, no deberias ingresar texto, deberias ingresar un id con una referencia a otra tabla.. mañana agregan temporales y tu tabla se rompe ;)

Comment: ¿En pocas palabras es mala practica hacerlo, aun si lo hiciera con Id?
Lo que no quiero es que mas adelante si se llegara insertar datos por T-SQL no tengan se respeten esas reglas.

Comment: Porque se ingresarian datos por fuera??? por un problema?? si es por eso, ese ingreso debe respetar igualmente las reglas de negocios... Las reglas del negocio son del negocio.. esto no es una regla de la DB.. mañana en lugar de 2, tenes 5 nombres, dos funcionan de una forma, 3 de otra, y vas a estar cambiando reglas en la DB a cada rato? ni hablar si tenes que levantar todo, o cambiar una restriccion...

Comment: Tienes mucha razón, creí que era lo correcto para dar mas consistencia a la información. Gracias por evitarme una locura..

Comment: Entonces es mejor hacer validaciones en la inserción de los datos por medio de una función de sql, store procedure o desde mi aplicación.

Answer (score 1):

No hagas caso a los que dicen que no se deben incluir las reglas de negocio en la base de datos. Si el sistema llega a cambiar y olvidan migrar esa regla, tu base de datos podría almacenar datos erróneos que luego hay que limpiar. Lo ideal es que tengas esa seguridad en múltiples capas.

Lo que pides se puede hacer con un `CHECK CONSTRAINT`.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Vacaciones (
   IDEmpleado      INT ,
   Fecha_Inicio     date NOT NULL,
   TipoContratoId   varchar( 20) NOT NULL --Debería ser un ID, pero lo dejo así para el ejemplo
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.Vacaciones ADD CONSTRAINT chkTipoContratoVacaciones CHECK (TipoContratoId IN('FIJO', 'INDEFINIDO'))

INSERT INTO dbo.Vacaciones VALUES(1, '20221106', 'FIJO');
INSERT INTO dbo.Vacaciones VALUES(2, '20221015', 'INDEFINIDO');
INSERT INTO dbo.Vacaciones VALUES(3, '20221021', 'TEMPORAL');

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Vacaciones;
```

Esto no quiere decir que tu código deba permitir pase cualquier dato y se valide hasta llegar a la tabla. Esta es solo la última linea de defensa para la integridad de tu base de datos. Piensa en que es como el portero del equipo de futbol. Lo ideal es que el balón se mantenga en posesión de tus otros jugadores, pero es mejor que haya alguien siempre cuidando la portería.

Answer (score 0):

Usted puede usar los constreñimientos de llaves foráneas para restringir los valores de la columna tipo contrato. Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Empleado (
   ID            INT CONSTRAINT PK_Empleado PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
   NombreEmpleado  VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
   TipoContratoId    INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.TipoContrato (
   TipoContratoId  INT CONSTRAINT PK_TipoContrato PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
   TipoContratoDescripcion  VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
)

INSERT INTO dbo.TipoContrato (TipoContratoDescripcion) VALUES
('FIJO'),
('INDEFINIDO');

ALTER TABLE Empleado ADD CONSTRAINT
   FK_Empleado_TipoContrato FOREIGN KEY (TipoContratoId) REFERENCES dbo.TipoContrato (TipoContratoId)
```

En este escenario, la columna TipoContratoId en la tabla Empleado puede asumir solamente valores 1 y 2 mostrados abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Morillo el escenario que planteas es común, pero no hubiese servido para lo que tenia pensado ya que en la tabla de Tipos de contrato que yo manejo, existen mas contratos y de todos esos tipos de contrato solo 2 se le pueden realizar el tramite de vacaciones. Gracias por tu gran aporte hermano.

Comment: @JamesJhairToroCantero Gracias a ti hermano por el feedback.

Answer (score 0):

La tabla de tipo de contrato podría tener un atributo que identifique si es o no posible utilizarla en la lógica que estás implementando.

Otra idea es, entiedo que tienes una serie de "procedimientos" que puedes hacer para cada tipo de contrato, es decir, a éstos les puedes "Tramitar Vacaciones" a otros podrás "Tramitar Descuentos" (Es un ejemplo) si ésto es así, yo haría una tabla de cruce donde tendría una tabla de Tipos de Contrato, otra de Tipos de Procedimiento y una final que relaciones Contratos con Procedimientos, así la regla de negocio quedaría configurable a nivel BD.

Saludos!